# Microsoft Store's "neutral" architecture vs MSI

Tags: windows-installer, microsoft-store

When you create a listing on the Microsoft store for MSI app, it gives you the choice of architecture - Intel 32/64, ARM 32/64, *or "neutral"*. However, every MSI (or EXE, for that matter) carries an architecture marker in the summary information, and "neutral" isn't one of the options.

Is it possible, somehow, to prepare a setup for an architecture neutral listing? Or does the store  dynamically replace the architecture with the desired target as people download?

Answer (score 0):

An x86 (internally "Intel") MSI will run on an ARM64 box, and, naturally, on x64 too. Couldn't test on ARM.

Will the store accept one is another question. Fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use WPF and target Any CPU, and create an installer as such, it will be a neutral EXE. So, it is possible.

Comment: Technically an EXE with IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_UNKNOWN for machine code is possible, I wonder though what's in the text section...